# How Get data with join django Rest framework from other table

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models first one is

```
class Event(models.Model):
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='events/images', default="")
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    event_organizer = models.ForeignKey(
    Organizer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_active': True})
```

and other one is

```
class additional_images(models.Model):
   # When a Event is deleted, upload models are also deleted
   event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   image = models.FileField(upload_to='events/images', null=True, blank=True, default="")
```

and serializer class is given by

```
class eventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id', 'main_image', 'event_name', 'event_address', 'event_organizer']
```

my question is how i get `additional_images` with `eventSerializer`.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/ add the `additional_images_set` to the `fields` or set `related_name` and use it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: thanks buddy `related_name` works perfectly and your both links are helpfull. I Post it as a answer how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Bear Brown**. his comment was helpful and I post it as a answer
Update my `additional_images` model

```
class additional_images(models.Model):

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                             related_name="additional_images",
                             related_query_name="additional_image",)
   image = models.FileField(upload_to='events/images', null=True, blank=True, default="")
```

And make serializer class for this

```
class additionalImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = additional_images
        fields = ['image']
```

And in `eventSerializer` class

```
class eventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    additional_images = additionalImagesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['additional_images', 'id', 'main_image', 'event_name', 
                  'event_address',  'event_organizer']
```

That's work Perfectly!

Comment: Is it possible to another serializer like history in which I can join both the event and addditional_image and serializer and access both tables fields If it possible can anyone explain it how

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `ForeignKey` and how to access the relation between them in the documentation.

But, you can do something like this:

1) (Optional) specify related_name:

```
class additional_images(models.Model):
   # When a Event is deleted, upload models are also deleted
   event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
```

2) You can now access it  with `event.images`. So you can use that in your serializer:

```
class eventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id', 'main_image', 'event_name', 'event_address', 'event_organizer', 'images']
```

Now you will get images as a list of image ids. If you have a image serialier, you can specify a nested serializer in your event serializer.

Code review comment: You have 3 classes, and each of them has different naming convention. Stick to one, preferably -> `EventSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class eventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.CharField(source='additional_images.get_image_url', read_only=True)
    additional_images = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=additional_images.objects.all())
    class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ['id','main_image', 'event_address',  'event_organizer', 'additional_images', 'image']
```

and define a get image url method in your models

```
class additional_images(models.Model):
   .........
   def get_image_url(self):
       returen "%s,%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)
```